# Why is this GAN not converging?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks

This GAN being trained with CelebA dataset doesn't seem to mode collapse, discriminator is not really over confident, and yet the quality is stuck on these rough Picasso-like generator images. Using Leaky-ReLU, strided conv instead of maxpool, and dampened truths helped a little, but still no better than this. Not sure what else to try. [training clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eb007xdmM6Y) Discriminator feed is in top left corner.

[image]